# Getting error "Object doesn't support property or method 'module' " when using angular.module ()

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, shim

Where ever i am making use of angular.module() in my code, that part fails when i access through the IE browser. In chrome everything works fine. 
Also the application where my code is present downgrades the IE version to 7 and renders the code.
I need to make angular.module() work in IE 7 .

below is the error :
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'module'

angular Js version i am using is 1.5.5

Also noticed a strange thing, on the first go, i get this error, but if i do a ctrl + f5 then the error goes away and app works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Angular doesn't support IE 8, let alone IE 7](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie):

> Note: AngularJS 1.3 has dropped support for IE8. Read more about it on
>   our blog. AngularJS 1.2 will continue to support IE8, but the core
>   team does not plan to spend time addressing issues specific to IE8 or
>   earlier.

Comment: I agree.. i came across similar other articles like this, but need to know are there any tweaks or plugins that could resolve this issue